# How to send external e-mail from device? (Exchange 2003)

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2003

I'd like to get external notifications on my iPhone from service monitors inside the network. The easiest way to do this is to have the devices send e-mails to my ATT SMS email (xxxxxxxxxx@txt.att.net).

However, while internal notifications work fine, it doesn't seem as if Exchange is allowing the relay of these messages to the outside world.

How can I have these devices (APC Matrix, Servers Alive, et al.) alert me anytime?

Thanks.
(Exchange 2003 SP2 on Windows Server 2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to get done is referred as allow SMTP relay. Normally exchange SMTP Virtual Server is configured to allow relay only from authenticated senders and quite often the devices sending out e-mails don't authenticate with the server they're relaying through.

There's quite an easy way to achieve this, and that's called allowing IP relay on Exchange.

- Open Exchange ESM, navigate down to the SMTP Virtual Server that'll be used to relay
- Open the properties of that SMTP Virtual Server, and then on Access Tab locate the section about 'Relay'.
- There you'll need to list down IP Addresses of devices and servers that'll need to relay out to external e-mail domains

Once exchange is configured on the devices you can use the exchange server IP/FQDN as a relay host for these outgoing emails.

Comment: Thanks Prayag - and all - for the tips. It turned out I had already added the IP address for the APC in the relay tab (thought this should allow external mailing long ago). It took a power outage and subsequent "warmstart" of the APC... and then the messages were sent out correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed to do. Found it in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, the servers sending alerts need to authenticate with the Exchange Server before attempting to send, else they will not be allowed to relay.

You can either setup an account in Exchange for these emails and set your applications to authenticate to this account when they send, or setup Exchange to allow anonymous relaying only from the IP addresses of these services. There is a good article [here](http://www.quantumsoftware.com.au/Support/KB/Article.aspx?ID=50) on how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if the "From:" address is not an address within the Exchange server's configured email domains, it won't pass it along. Messages like, "powerchute@ahups1" will get bounced, but "powerchute@ahups1.maildomain.org" will get passed along. In general. It just may be that the Exchange servers need to have that IP address added to the allowed-relay list.

Answer (score 0):

Sam is correct.  Unauthenticated connections cannot relay by default in Exchange 2000/2003.  What I did is create a second virtual SMTP server on another IP address and check the Anonymous authentication option in the Access tab.  Then I configure any internal notification system to connect to that IP address.  Since this virtual SMTP is not used by your normal mail flow, you are not compromising your normal mail traffic.  If desired, you can set up IP restrictions on the virtual SMTP server for each notification server so that you don't get unauthenticated email coming from unknown sources.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup what Sam mentioned above and has worked successfully in the past. It seems to be the easiest route.